# Google app script run function for sheets one by one

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google script which starts like below,

```
function popForm() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var numberRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
....
....
```

I have more sheets like `Sheet2`, `Sheet3`, `Sheet4` etc. I would like to run same `popForm` function for all these sheets. Can I do it in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work

```
function popForm() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets()
  for (var s=0; s<sheets.length; s++) {
    var sheet = sheets[s];
    var numberRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
    ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation:

- Essentially, you need to iterate over all the sheets of your
  spreadsheet file. To accomplish that you can create a new function
  `runForAllSheets` that calls `popForm(sheet)` for every sheet using
  [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- If you will, you can define instead your own custom list of sheets that you would like to be passed in `popForm(sheet)`:

  ```
  var sheets = ['Sheet2','Sheet3','Sheet4 '];
  ```

---

### Solution:

You just need to execute only `runForAllSheets()`:

```
function runForAllSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); // All sheets
  //var sheets = ['Sheet2','Sheet3','Sheet4 ']; // Chosen sheets
  sheets.forEach(sh=>{
   popForm(sh);
  })
}


function popForm(sheet) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var numberRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  // ....
}
```